# command prompt equivalent in linux

Tags: python, command-prompt

i am working on the following script,

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
def sample1():
    os.system('start cmd /k python script1.py')

def sample2():
    os.system('start cmd /k python script2.py')


def main():
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=sample1)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=sample2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works well in windows(python), but is it possible in linux using the terminal??.

What i required is "command prompt in linux". How to get it, any ways??

Comment: Why are you starting a **Python** script from the command line which you open with **Python**? Why not cutout the middle man and just call the Python scripts from `main()`.

Comment: because i am integrating two scripts into one, and so i want to print the output of each script to a different file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to launch a terminal where you can see output of your script you can use:

```
os.system("xterm -hold -e python script1.py")
```

Comment: The window comes and goes in a second, is it possible to make it stay for sometime??

Comment: os.system("xterm -hold -e python script1.py")

Comment: This is wat i was looking at!! :)@kostya